# Using Gathering/Automating information from Excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple Excel files with sheets that show bank account information in the picture. I want to show a daily beginning and ending balance for each account and also show a total of the transactions that took place on each account with a daily closing balance. What is a good way to go about doing this? The end result with be a sheet or a table with each daily closing amount and each total of the transactions that took place in the various daily accounts
[image]

Answer (score 0):

put a table like this in G9 onwards, showing all the bank accounts listed in column A:

[image]

then put this formula in H9

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET($B$6,MATCH($G9,$A$6:$A$200,0),0,MATCH($G10,$A$6:$A$200,0)-MATCH($G9,$A$6:$A$200,0)),$B$7,OFFSET(C$6,MATCH($G9,$A$6:$A$200,0),0,MATCH($G10,$A$6:$A$299,0)-MATCH($G9,$A$6:$A$200,0)))
```

copy the formula down next to the bank account numbers and to the right 3 more columns (4) in total

this should work as long as your data isn't long than 200 rows.  if it is change all the 200's in the code to a number larger than your last row.

*it may struggle for the last bank account, if it does add `end` in a cell just below you data in column A and `end` as a final entry in that table built from `G9` onwards, also make sure that the 200's cover the row end is in or update them to do so.*

Finally let us know how it goes and mark the answer accepted if it does what you need :)